# How does cpu cache handle large memory objects?

Tags: optimization, cpu-cache

**Scenario**:

- Cache (L1) size (`CS`): 32kB
- Line size (`LS`): 64B
- Associativity (`A`): 8
- Set size (`SS`): 512B (`A` * `LS`)
- Sets (`S`): 64 (`C` / `SS`)
- Read/written object (`O`) has size greater than `LS`

**Assumptions** (correct me if invalid):

- Virtual memory blocks (of size 4kB (`SS` * `A`) denoted as `B`) are mapped in modulo-like manner to sets. In other words, addresses `0x0 : 0xFFFF` (block index (`BI`) 0) are mapped to set 0, `0x1000 : 0x1FFF` (`BI` 1) are mapped to 1, and so forth.
- Request of reading/writing (no non-temporal writes/reads are used) a given address `A` requires finding its `BI` and then moving it to the assigned set. For instance, `A` = 0x4600A will have `BI` = 70. This `BI` is mapped to set 6 (`BI` % `S`).
- In order to properly (without misalignment) r/w an object (`O`) to cache, an alignment of `LS` is required.

**Questions**:

1. Will the `O` be serially aligned in the cache or it can take (for instance) free slots 0 & 4 & 5, instead of 0 & 1 & 2?
2. What is the cost (penalty) of retrieving partitioned `O` from cache? Assume that the `O` isn't partitioned across several `B`.
3. The same question as above, but in case when `O` is placed in two `B`, thus two sets are used.
4. What will happen if the `O` size is larger than the `SS` (512B)? Will it move the data to L2 and step-by-step move data to L1? Will it use other sets?
5. What if L2 (and L3 for that matter) is too small for all the data?

Comment: And how is that related to C++11?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Mainly because of `alignas()` which provides easy and standardized access to alignment manipulation. When you start aligning data to optimize cache performance I believe it's natural to ask for the cost of caching large objects.

Comment: Uhh. It sounds *a lot* like premature optimizations.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz So any lower level optimization is considered premature? I am not pointing and saying: look guys, this is definitely the performance bottleneck of my code! Basing on the my previous experiences, proper cache usage gives HUGE performance boost, thus I fail to see why this question is irrelevant in terms of general program optimization.

Answer (score 1):

> Virtual memory blocks (of size 4kB (SS * A) denoted as B) are mapped
>   in modulo-like manner to sets. In other words, addresses 0x0 : 0xFFFF
>   (block index (BI) 0) are mapped to set 0, 0x1000 : 0x1FFF (BI 1) are
>   mapped to 1, and so forth.

**Transfer between L1 cache and the memory hierarchy:**
the transfer unit between the L1 cache and the following level of the memory hierarchy is a block of line size (LS) bytes. That is, to your L1 cache, memory is structured in 64 bytes blocks (LS bytes).

**Correspondence between memory blocks and cache entries:**
consecutive memory blocks are mapped to cache lines of consecutive sets. Hence, block 0 (addresses `0x0000 : 0x003F`) is mapped to a cache line at set 0, block 1 (addresses `0x0040 : 0x007F`) is mapped to a cache line at set 1, and so forth.

---

> Request of reading/writing (no non-temporal writes/reads are used) a
>   given address A requires finding its BI and then moving it to the
>   assigned set. For instance, A = 0x4600A will have BI = 70. This BI is
>   mapped to set 6 (BI % S).

The correct procedure to find the block identifier (or index) and the set index (SI) is the following:

```
 BI = A >> LS = 0x4600A >> 6 = 0x1180
 SI = BI & (S-1) = 0x1180 & 0x3F = 0x0000
 (when S is a power of two, BI & (S-1) = BI  mod S)
```

---

> In order to properly (without misalignment) r/w an object (O) to
>   cache, an alignment of LS is required.

That is not necessary. O does not need to be block-aligned.

---

> Q1. Will the O be serially aligned in the cache or it can take (for
>   instance) free slots 0 & 4 & 5, instead of 0 & 1 & 2?

`O` blocks will be stored in consecutive sets with cache line granularity (set k, k+1, …, S-1, 0, 1, …) .

> Q2. What is the cost (penalty) of retrieving partitioned O from cache?
>   Assume that the O isn't partitioned across several B.
>   Q3. The same question as above, but in case when O is placed in two B,
>   thus two sets are used.

I assume your are interested in the cost of the CPU reading the `O` words from cache.
Supposing `O` is referenced sequentially, the number of cache accesses will be equal to the number of referenced words. I think the cost does not depend on the blocks being in the same or in different sets (at least in a multiported cache).

> Q4. What will happen if the O size is larger than the SS (512B)? Will
>   it move the data to L2 and step-by-step move data to L1? Will it use
>   other sets?
>
> Q5. What if L2 (and L3 for that matter) is too small for all the data?

If a block has to be allocated to a set with no free cache lines, a block has to be selected in order to be evicted (victim block). The replacement policy select the victim block according to an [**algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms) (LRU, pLRU, random).

Comment: I can't vote either way since this topic is way out of my depth, but I wish SO had more Q&As like this one. Verbal +1 for the time being.